# Laravel Get All Rows From Different Ids

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

today i was just practicing my skills and got stuck. I just want to fetch data from the database using specific ids which i put inside my session as an array. The problem is, i cant find a way to fetch all the data that includes these ids. 
here's my cart checkout method

```
public function checkout(){
    $uniqid = session('products');
    $post=Post::find($uniqid);
    return view('pages.checkout')->with('post',$post);
  }
```

I am getting no data, even if i try to get something i only get one field when there's something like 7 of them.
Here's the session products array

```
0   "15be4aa3b55f10"
1   "15be4814ceb2a0"
2   "15be4814ceb2a0"
3   "15be4aa3b55f10"
4   "15be4aa3b55f10"
5   "15be4aa3b55f10"
6   "15be4aa3b55f10"
7   "15be4aa3b55f10"
```

Comment: Can u add result of dd(session('products')); to your question.

Comment: you are using `find` it will only return 1 value.

Comment: You can foreach session value then using collection, you can have all results.

Comment: what does `$uniqid` look like when you return it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `find` query returns single row of data. If you want to fetch more than 1 data, use the `all` query:

```
$post = Post::all();
```

or if you want to get all data with the same id as your `$uniqid`, use the `where` query:

```
$post = Post::where('column_name', $uniqid)->get();
```

**EDIT**

IF your session has many id, you may want to loop and find all the data with the same `id` as your `$uniqid`

```
public function checkout(){
   $products = []; 
   foreach(session('products') as $session){
      $post=Post::find($session->id);
      $products[] = $post;
   }
   return view('pages.checkout')->with('products ',$products);
}
```

Comment: Done it this way and it worked !   

public function checkout(){
    $products = [];
       foreach(session('products') as $session){
          $post = Post::where('unique_id',$session)->get();
          $products[] = $post;
       }
       return view('pages.checkout')->with('products', $products);
     }

thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

you may try this:

```
public function checkout(){
    $uniqid = session('products');

    $products = Post::whereIn('unique_id', $uniqid)->get();
    return view('pages.checkout')->with('products',$products);
 }
```

where *whereIn* method takes a field name and array of values

From laravel [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#where-clauses):

> The whereIn method verifies that a given column's value is contained within the given array

Answer (score 0):

You should use whereIn() method to fetch records against multiple ids. do like this

```
  public function checkout(){
    $uniqidsArray= session('products');
    $post=DB::table('yourTableName')
                    ->whereIn('id', $uniqIdsArray)
                    ->get();
    return view('pages.checkout')->with('post',$post);
  }
```

Comment: All ids must be stored in an array then you can use whereIn() method.